# Find record which is missing in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question concerning a more efficient sql query which will select records from driving table, which is missing in second tables. Tables have more than 23k rows, and join takes too long.

Is there any way to make it faster? According to me, the following query loops through whole table

I used

```
SELECT * FROM orders
JOIN orderID USING(Order_id)
WHERE orderID != Order_id
```

Comment: 23k records should not make join slow, if the joining keys are indexed.

Comment: Have you tried NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `left join`.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN 
     SecondTable st
     ON o.orderID = st.Order_id
WHERE st.Order_id IS NULL;
```

I find it unlikely that the second table is called `Order_id`, so I've called it `SecondTable` in this query.  You probably don't need the columns from the non-existent record, so I've limited them to columns from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a cartesian product of both tables. What you want is to to a regular LEFT JOIN with an appropriate where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
JOIN orderID USING(Order_id)
ON orders.orderID = orderID.Order_id
WHERE orderID.Order_id IS NULL;
```